# Timeout alert message causes infinite loop in React page

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, timeout, alert

I am making an app the is supposed to flash a message indicating user creation success or failure. I am using deno's fresh framework which employs "preact". Preact is essentially a minimal version of react so just assume that what I'm doing would work the same in a React page.

My webpage code looks like this:

```
// import { useState } from "preact/hooks";
import { useState, useEffect } from "preact/hooks";
import { Handlers, PageProps } from "$fresh/server.ts";
import UserDb from "../database.ts";

interface CreatorProps {
  email: string,
  key: string
}

export default function Creator(props: CreatorProps) {
  const [alertPointer, setAlertPointer] = useState(0);
  const [alertInst, setAlertInst] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    function createAlert() {
      if (alertPointer === 0) {
        null;
      } else if (alertPointer === 1) {
        setAlertInst(
          <div class="bg-blue-100 border-t border-b border-blue-500 text-blue-700 px-4 py-3" role="alert">
            <p class="font-bold">User Creation Succeeded</p>
            <p class="text-sm">A new user was added to the database</p>
          </div>
        );
      } else {
        setAlertInst(
          <div class="bg-red-100 border border-red-400 text-red-700 px-4 py-3 rounded relative" role="alert">
            <strong class="font-bold">User Creation Failed</strong>
            <span class="block sm:inline">Are you sure you entered in a valid email and key?</span>
            <span class="absolute top-0 bottom-0 right-0 px-4 py-3">
              <svg class="fill-current h-6 w-6 text-red-500" role="button" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20"><title>Close</title><path d="M14.348 14.849a1.2 1.2 0 0 1-1.697 0L10 11.819l-2.651 3.029a1.2 1.2 0 1 1-1.697-1.697l2.758-3.15-2.759-3.152a1.2 1.2 0 1 1 1.697-1.697L10 8.183l2.651-3.031a1.2 1.2 0 1 1 1.697 1.697l-2.758 3.152 2.758 3.15a1.2 1.2 0 0 1 0 1.698z"/></svg>
            </span>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
    const timeId = setTimeout(() => {
      // After 3 seconds set the show value to false
      setAlertPointer(0);
      setAlertInst("");
    }, 3000)

    function removeItem() {
      console.log("rm item start");
      clearTimeout(timeId)
      console.log("rm item finished");
      console.log(timeId);
      console.log(alertPointer);
      console.log(alertInst);
    }
    createAlert();
    removeItem();
  }, [alertPointer, alertInst]);
  
  async function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const emailInput = event.target.email;
    const ageInput = event.target.key;
    const resp = await createNewUser(emailInput.value, ageInput.value);
    return resp
  };

  async function createNewUser(email, key) {
    const rawPosts = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/createUser', {
      "method": "POST",
      "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/json"
      },
      "body": JSON.stringify({
        email: email,
        key: key,
      })
    });
    const respns = JSON.parse(await rawPosts.json());
    if (respns.isUserCreated) {
      setAlertPointer(1);
    } else {
      setAlertPointer(2);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {alertInst}
      <h1 class="text rounded-lg p-4 my-8"> Search </h1>
      <form method="post" onSubmit={async (e) => handleSubmit(e)}>
        <input class="center rounded-lg p-4 my-8" id="email" name="email" />
        <input class="center rounded-lg p-4 my-8" id="key" name="key" />
        <br />
        <button
          class="px-5 py-2.5 text-sm font-medium bg-blue-600 rounded-md shadow disabled:(bg-gray-800 border border-blue-600 opacity-50 cursor-not-allowed)"
          type="submit">Submit
        </button>
      </form>
      <br />
      {/* <ul>
        {results.map((name) => <li key={name}>{name}</li>)}
      </ul> */}
    </div>
  );
};
```

When I create a user that succeeds the page looks like this:
[image]

But the message never disappears and the web console looks like this:
[image]

How do I fix this? How do I make the alert indicating success or failure vanish after 3 seconds?

Comment: Is `alertInst` supposed to be a string? Why are you storing JSX into React state? This is generally considered anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I see is that once the `alertPointer` state is updated to a non-zero value it's never set back to `0`. The `removeItem` is called and clears the running timeout that was just instantiated to reset the `alertPointer` state back to 0. `alertPointer` equals `1` and state updates are continued to be enqueued.

```
useEffect(() => {
  function createAlert() {
    if (alertPointer === 0) {
      null;
    } else if (alertPointer === 1) {
      setAlertInst(....);
    } else {
      setAlertInst(....)
    }
  }

  const timeId = setTimeout(() => { // (1) <-- timeout instantiated
    // After 3 seconds set the show value to false
    setAlertPointer(0);
    setAlertInst("");
  }, 3000)

  function removeItem() {
    console.log("rm item start");
    clearTimeout(timeId); // (3) <-- cleared
    console.log("rm item finished");
    console.log(timeId);
    console.log(alertPointer);
    console.log(alertInst);
  }

  createAlert();
  removeItem(); // (2) <-- timeout cleared
}, [alertPointer, alertInst]);
```

You should store the timer id in a React ref (*via the `useRef` hook*) and return `useEffect` cleanup function in the case the component unmounts *prior* to the timeout expiring. This allows the normal operation of the timeout while the component is mounted.

Example:

```
const timerIdRef = useRef();

// Clear any running timeouts when the component unmounts
useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    clearTimeout(timerIdRef.current);
  };
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  function createAlert() {
    if (alertPointer === 0) {
      null;
    } else if (alertPointer === 1) {
      setAlertInst(....);
    } else {
      setAlertInst(....)
    }
  }

  timerIdRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
    // After 3 seconds set the show value to false
    setAlertPointer(0);
    setAlertInst("");
  }, 3000)

  createAlert();
}, [alertPointer, alertInst]);
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me. I think we're a lot closer. No it counts up to 3000, but it keeps going and doesn't remove the alerts. https://gist.github.com/ChristianOConnor/60233fd48de0d2176df3fbd0edf0784c. That's my new code. Do you see the problem?

Comment: @ChristianOConnor I can take a look, but it would be easier if you could instead try to create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code we could inspect live.

Comment: Wait I think I fixed it, if you agree with this please edit this answer to reflect the change and I'll accept it. I removed `return () => { removeItem(); }` from the useEffect function. It seems to work now. Is that safe? It seems to work perfectly.

Comment: @ChristianOConnor Sure, seems fine if you don't need it. You'll still want a cleanup function to run to at least clear out any running timers in the untimely case one is running when the component unmounts. I'll update my answer to reflect your change along with my additional suggestion.

Comment: Awesome thanks! And yes I would like additional code to clear out any running timers thanks!

Comment: @ChristianOConnor Ok, please check again now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248184/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-christianoconnor).